# Algorithm In LaTeX Elsevier Template

Tags: algorithms, elsarticle, algorithmic

Actually, I wrote algorithm first in general LaTeX format and done successfully. 
Following algorithm packages I had used:

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

But when I copied same algorithm code in the **Elsvier LaTeX template** it's not working correctly. Please help me to get out this problem. The class which I am using in `elsearticle` format:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
```

**Now I am providing some more information: Code and Output**

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}%do
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\State $a$ is AB valyes, $T$ is dec, $R\textsubscript{Data}$ is NOTHING\;
\State A\textsubscript{Ab} is values\;
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $R\textsubscript{Data} \gets abs \Comment{my name is Xyz}$ \;
\State $L_i \gets $ Labeling my name    \Comment(i=1,2,3)\;
\State $T_{0}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($start$)\;
\State $T_{end}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($end$)\;
\Procedure {who} {$A\textsubscript{ab}$, $D\textsubscript{i}$}
          \For {$s\gets A_{ab}(1)$ \TO $D_{Data}(end)$} 
               \If{AB}
                  \State No Matter
               \Else 

                 \State yes $A_{b}$ nothing special
               \EndIf
               \For {$F_{S}\gets 1 \leq 6$}
                    \State $S_{F}\gets F(T_{sw})$
               \EndFor
          \EndFor
\EndProcedure

\Procedure {where}{$A_{ab}$}
                \For {Man}
                   \State Guess where I am
                \EndFor
\EndProcedure
 \caption{STGY}
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Tex Stackexchange. You should include more information. At this moment, it is difficult to help you.

Comment: In addition to Karlos comment, please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test to see your problem (without having to guess for example your preamble). As it sits now we have to guess a lot about your document and thus might make mistakes.

Comment: please first try to give me some information. After that, If not solved then I'll provide you some information (code)

Comment: A statement such as "Its not working correctly" is not actionable. Please be more specific. E.g., do you get warning and/or messages? At which point do these messages show up? Do they show up while still in the preamble, or later on in the document?

Comment: In addition to karlo, daleif and @Mico comments, to guess where the problem is in your file, get to the last point at which you were able to compile successfully, then try to locate and share with us what new commands or packages you have added that would be the problematic code. You can provide the minimal working example by not including those potential "problematic" commands/packages then ask how to include them properly. You don't have to worry about stealing your code :)

Comment: Now I think I provided enough information. Please help me out to this problem

Comment: That sniplet is not even remotely compilable, where is `\begin/end{document} `. BTW algorithm is a float, you cannot have `\State` there, all the algorithm has to go inside the algorithmic env

Comment: @daleif I used  `\begin/end{document}` in my editor. If `\State` should not be there then What should I use instead `\State`

Comment: Your mwe is still incomplete, others who are trying to help still has to add stuff to it for it to even have a chance of compiling, this is a waste of their time. As I wrote the entire algorithm code has to go inside the algorithmic environment, that is the only place State is defined.

Comment: BTW: you are aware that you cannot mix and match pseudocode packages, some of them are not compatible. Your issue here has nothing to do with the Elsevier template. Most of what is  in that algorithm code is wrong, or should not be used like that. It will not even work with the standard `article` class.

Comment: @delief did you run my code in your editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your given code there are some issues:

1. First of all you have no `\begin{document}`.
2. I commented some `\;` at the end of some lines.
3. You need to change `\TO` to `\to`.
4. Some `$` are missing.

Please see the following compilable code

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{algorithm}% <=================http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% <========== http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{hyperref} % <===============================================


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $a$ is AB valyes, $T$ is dec, $R\textsubscript{Data}$ is NOTHING%\;
\State $A\textsubscript{Ab}$ is values%\;  % <===========================
\State $R\textsubscript{Data} \gets $ abs \Comment{my name is Xyz} %\;
\State $L_i \gets $ Labeling my name    \Comment(i=1,2,3)%\;
\State $T_{0}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($start$)%\;
\State $T_{end}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($end$)%\;
\Procedure {who} {$A\textsubscript{ab}$, $D\textsubscript{i}$}
  \For {$s\gets A_{ab}(1) \to D_{Data}(end)$} % <=======================
    \If{AB}
      \State No Matter
    \Else 
      \State yes $A_{b}$ nothing special
    \EndIf
    \For {$F_{S}\gets 1 \leq 6$}
      \State $S_{F}\gets F(T_{sw})$
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\EndProcedure

\Procedure {where}{$A_{ab}$}
                \For {Man}
                   \State Guess where I am
                \EndFor
\EndProcedure
 \caption{STGY}\label{STGY}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting algorithmn]

BTW: package `hyperref` should be called as last package in your case.