# Error Message in Displaying Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, thesis, algpseudocode

I am writing a thesis, and there I have three files, one is main, another one is Chapter and the last one is a.tex.

- main.tex is using to call the chapter.
- I have written main algorithm in a.tex. So I am calling that file in chapter.tex.
  But it shows the errors?

**Errors**

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \State
! Extra \endcsname.\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname\relax \def \ALG@thisblock... \State
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \State
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \State
! Extra \endcsname.\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname\relax \def \ALG@thisblock... \State
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \State
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \State
! Extra \endcsname.\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname\relax \def \ALG@thisblock... \State
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \State
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \State
! Extra \endcsname.\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname\relax \def \ALG@thisblock... \State
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \State
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \State
! Extra \endcsname.\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname\relax \def \ALG@thisblock... \State
! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\ALG@currentblock@0 \Procedure
```

**Package:**

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

**a.tex** **(Code file)**

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
%\SetAlgoLined
%\KwResult{Write here the result }
\State $a$ is BAC , $T$ is trignotmatric, $R\textsubscript{Data}$ is my symbolic data\;
\State RS \textsubscript{Data} is textual data\;
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $R\textsubscript{Data} \gets hi$ w.r.t $j$ \Comment{ABC} \;
\State $L_i \gets $ FSC \Comment(i=1,2,3)\;
\State Remove ABC\;
\State $T_{0}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($start$)\;
$T_{new}$}
\Procedure {multi} {$ab\textsubscript{Data}$, $g\textsubscript{i}$}
          \For {$s\gets RS_{dd}(1)$ \TO $RS_{aa}(end)$} 
           \State $ff_{sw}\gets S_{ddd} \times W_{L}$ 
               \If{vvvv }
                  \State np such 
               \Else 
                 \State $dd_{ss}\gets sss_{ffff} \times aada_{sadada} \times \frac{O_{LP}}{100}$ 

               \EndIf
               \For {$F_{S}\gets 1 \leq 6$}
                    \State $E_{feature}\gets F(T_{sw}
               \EndFor
          \EndFor
\EndProcedure

\Procedure {myz}{$sa_{aa}$}
                \For {each value}
                   \State Not something 
                \EndFor
\EndProcedure
 \caption{MYALGORIHTM}
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
%\end{filecontents}
```

Please help me out to this problem?

Comment: You have to wrap your first two states into the `algorithmic` environment, too. The given code would not work nevertheless: Without `amsmath` the `\;` at the end of the lines (which are not needed at all as there is no text afterwards) throws an error, you have an extra `}` in `$T_{new}$}` (which seems to miss something like `\State` beforehand, too), `\TO` is undefined and `$E_{feature}\gets F(T_{sw}` is missing the end of the math mode.

Comment: Same code is working in other latex file but here its not working.

Comment: Sorry, but your code for the algorithmn can not work. See my answer for a corrected code for the algorithmn ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but your question is nearly the same you asked before, where I already gave you an answer: [old question with my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485657/16550)

In this answer I already told you to -- for example -- change `$ \TO $` to correct `\to` etc.

I do not have your used class  `MastersDoctoralThesis` but I know it is sayed to be very problematic. So if you can not test it yourself please add a link to that class you used in your question.

For this answer I simply use `article`.

Please see this corrected code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $a$ is BAC , $T$ is trignotmatric, $R\textsubscript{Data}$ is my symbolic data%\;
\State RS \textsubscript{Data} is textual data%\;
\State $R\textsubscript{Data} \gets hi$ w.r.t $j$ \Comment{ABC} %\;
\State $L_i \gets $ FSC \Comment(i=1,2,3)%\;
\State Remove ABC%\;
\State $T_{0}\gets R_{Data}$.$T$($start$)%\;
%$T_{new}$}
\Procedure {multi} {$ab\textsubscript{Data}$, $g\textsubscript{i}$}
  \For {$s\gets RS_{dd}(1) \to RS_{aa}(end)$} % <============= \TO -> \to inside $ $
    \State $ff_{sw}\gets S_{ddd} \times W_{L}$ 
    \If{vvvv }
      \State np such 
    \Else 
      \State $dd_{ss}\gets sss_{ffff} \times aada_{sadada} \times \frac{O_{LP}}{100}$ 
    \EndIf
    \For {$F_{S}\gets 1 \leq 6$}
      \State $E_{feature}\gets F(T_{sw}$ % <==============
    \EndFor
  \EndFor
\EndProcedure

\Procedure {myz}{$sa_{aa}$}
                \For {each value}
                   \State Not something 
                \EndFor
\EndProcedure
 \caption{MYALGORIHTM}
 \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting algorithmn]

Please see that I once again commented your wrong `\;` at the end od the first `\State` lines of you. I already did that in your old question.

**Please study given answers and learn from them!**

Comment: Yes, its work. Thank you so much for your help.